# Automatically download an xml file from URI with download popup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webclient

ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor:

I've been working at this for a bit, so I apologize if I'm missing something obvious, but I will truly appreciate any assistance that could be offered.

In a nutshell, what I'm looking to do is download an XML file from a URI using C#.  It ought to be pretty straightforward, but the URI leads to a blank page with a download prompt popup populated with a dynamically created filename.

I can't provide the URI due to its confidential nature, but here is the code I've been toying with. (Forgive my ignorance on this matter, it's the first time I've tried anything like this)

```
byte[] data;
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
{
    data = Client.DownloadData(uriString + fileString);
}
File.WriteAllBytes(dirString + fileString, data);
```

I've also tried:

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
{
    Client.DownloadFile(uriString + fileString, dirString + fileString);
}
```

To be honest, this code doesn't really work for me.  The downloaded files aren't correct.  The XML files appear to contain the code from the webpage they've been downloaded from, and if I try something like an image, the image is broken.  So, again, any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"The XML files appear to contain the code from the webpage they've been downloaded from"` - Are you sure the URI is correct?  Is it the URI for the actual file you're looking for, or just a page which shows the file?  Does the target website require further actions before serving the file?  If the URI is sensitive, can you supply an equal example that we might be able to see?  (Also, what does this have to do with ASP.NET, MVC 4, and/or Razor?)

Comment: Hello, thanks for your fast reply.  The URI leads to a blank page that initiates a download popup for the file in question.  Previously we would manually download the file from this popup, however, I'm trying to automate the process to improve ease of use. I'll post a link when I've found something that acts the same way.  I mentioned ASP.NET and so on in case it might be important information, sometimes I've seen fixes require a bit of JavaScript or something of the like.

Comment: `"a blank page that initiates a download popup"` - I'm curious what this "popup" is and how the content is actually served.  One thing you can do is capture the actual HTTP requests and responses in some browser debugging tools (like Firebug or Chrome developer tools) and see what this interaction is actually doing.  What you're looking for is an HTTP response which is only the file content itself, but it sounds like what you're getting is some HTML which somehow initiates a second request for the file.

Comment: I will look at it with Firebug. Thank you, that's a good idea.  This is the closest example I've found to show the URI's behavior, with the exception of filetype. Link for Firefox_Setup.exe [link](http://downloader.ez-download.com/download.php?id=9527e2a6879911e89a89c8977cfd2a9681f77e59B&z=0&p=eyJweSI6ImV6IiwicnMiOiJnb29nbGUiLCJydCI6InNlYXJjaCIsImMiOiJjYSIsIm8iOiJ3aW43IiwiYiI6ImNoMjgiLCJ1X2lkIjoiZXpfNTFmN2JlNTE2Y2EzNTEuODA3NDE0ODIiLCJwYV9pZCI6IjAiLCJzdF9pZCI6IjAiLCJzcF9pZCI6IjAwMDYtMDAwMCIsInRzIjoxMzc1MTkwNjA5LCJrdyI6ImRvd25sb2FkIGZpcmVmb3giLCJjdSI6ImRvd25sb2FkIGZpcmVmb3giLCJjYSI6bnVsbH0%3D)

Comment: It appears that the previous link has broken, it must have been only temporary.  To replicate go [here](http://www.ez-download.com/mozilla-firefox/?kw=download+firefox&subid=EZFFCA&cust=download+firefox&type=firefox&gclid=CKGR0J-o17gCFZFaMgodYWcA6Q&utm_campaign=EZFFCA&fwd=1). Right-clicking 'Download' and using the link address in a new tab will show the example behavior.  Seems it's nigh impossible to get the necessary information from the actual URI using Firebug.  I'm looking into other options in the meantime.  But I'll update this when a solution has been found.

Comment: Looks like I can't help debug that.  The "EZ Download" site tells me that it only supports Windows.  (Which implies to me that it's probably doing something non-HTTP-standard somewhere, which is part of the problem you're facing.)

Comment: @David Thanks for taking a look.  For now, it'll be going to a later update. I'll be in touch with the developer of the site directly tomorrow, should shed some light on it.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The URI that you are using is probably wrong. You are using the URI that opens the popup page. The popup page should be doing another GET to the dynamically generated file.

To automate this process, you should use a WebRequest to get the contents of the popup page. Scrape the contents of the page to get the actual URL to download the file. Then use the code you have written to download the file.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("PopupUrl");
var response = request.GetResponse();
string url = GetUrlFromResponseByRegExOrXMLParsing();
var client = new WebClient();
webClient.DownloadFile(url, filePath);
```